# Why does `print foo.communicate()[0]` differ from `print foo.communicate()`"

Tags: python, subprocess

Here is the situation:

I've got a command I'm running:

```
import subprocess
foo = subprocess.Popen('ls /', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,\
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Pretty basic, right? And I've figured out that I can do stuff with the output with `.communicate()`, like this:

```
print foo.communicate()
```

Which works great and produces the output that the documentation for subprocess.communicate suggests it should, a tuple:

```
('bin\nboot\ncdrom\n[...stuff redacted for brevity...]tmp\nusr\nvar\nvmlinuz\n', None)
```

Notice the `\n` newlines in there. And I've discovered that just asking for the first element of the tuple produces output with newlines, like this:

```
>>> print foo.communicate()[0]
bin
boot
cdrom
[...stuff redacted for brevity...]
tmp
usr
var
vmlinuz
```

But what I don't understand is WHY printing with just the first element produces the newlines. Don't get me wrong, it is great, and I'm glad I can do it without a loop, but I'd like to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python when you call something like `print obj`, you're actually calling the `__str__` on the object and then interpreting the result as a string.

So for example say you have:

```
      >>> a = ('foo\nbar', '5')
      >>> print a
      ('foo\nbar', '5')
```

As you've noticed. But if you do something like:

```
      >>> class mytuple(tuple):
              def __str__(self):
                  return ''.join(self)
      >>> b = mytuple(a)
      >>> print b
      foo
      bar5
```

This subclass of the tuple type goes beyond the standard `__str__` and builds a string composed out the string representations of its constituent parts.

The reason this isn't done in the general case is that you never know what objects could be inserted in a tuple, or list - not all objects have string-able representations.

Answer (score 2):

`foo.communicate()` returns a `tuple`. If you write `foo.communicate()[0]` you retrieve a first element in that tuple. Since this element is just a string, python interpreter prints it to your screen, printing `\n` as newlines.

When you print a tuple from `foo.communinicate()` you see the `\n` characters, but this is just a difference in the way the tuples are printed, the newlines are always there.